# How to read bytes from a Socket in Haskell

Tags: sockets, networking, haskell

I'm trying to read a number of Bytes from a socket in Haskell. Bascially I want to do something equivalent to this:

```
client_socket.recv(255) #(Python)
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's Network.Socket, which has recvFrom and recvBufFrom.  The first one assumes you want a String, which you certainly don't want if you want binary data.  The second one uses a pointer, which you probably don't want to deal with.  There's also socketToHandle, which is very useful.

However, my recommendation is the **network-bytestring** library.  It supports both lazy and strict bytestrings.  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-bytestring

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of beginner questions, it's not a bad idea to check out [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/sockets-and-syslog.html) first.

And as a general rule of thumb, you should always look at [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/) for libraries and documentation. To search for a function, [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) and [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) are your friends.

Comment: Thanks Wei Hu. I've got a copy of RWH - but unfortunately I'm in the middle of moving house and it's ended up in a box. But I'd forgotten about the online one. Thanks for the reminder!